# How reduce file size of GPX files with GDAL OGR2OGR?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, gpx

I want to reduce the file size of some gpx files with gdal ogr2ogr.

When I use simplify like the following command in Mac Terminal the file size does not really shrink:

```
ogr2ogr -simplify 0.00001 output.gpx input.gpx
```

And when I do the following it gives me an error permission denied:

```
input.gpx do ogr2ogr -simplify 0.00001
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144015/how-does-ogr2ogr-simplify-work any use?

Comment: Simplify won't have an effect on a point.

Comment: Is there any other command to reduce the track points?

Answer (score 0):

I have now done it with [GPSBabel](https://www.gpsbabel.org/)

- For one file:

`gpsbabel -w -r -t -i gpx -f /Users/user/Downloads/gpx-files1/file.gpx -x simplify,count=100 -o gpx -F /Users/aronsommer/Downloads/gpx-files2/file.gpx`

- For multiple files:

`for f in /Users/user/Downloads/gpx-files1/*.gpx; do /Applications/GPSBabelFE.app/Contents/MacOS/gpsbabel -w -r -t -i gpx -f $f -x simplify,count=100 -o gpx -F $f; done`

- If command not found: gpsbabel

Use `/Applications/GPSBabelFE.app/Contents/MacOS/gpsbabel`